# Alert box malfuction

Tags: javascript, php, database, search, alert

I have a problem with the script code . I have an alert box which displays the results of the search but the problem is that it displays the previous result not the current one. The first time it gives null ,then it works by giving the previous result. What is wrong? .Thanks in advance

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userCountry LIKE '%".$q."%'"); 
//Replace table_name with your table name and `thing_to_search` with the column you want to search
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == "0" || $q == ""){
        $output = '<h2 style="color:white;">No player found!</h2>';
    }else{
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $s[] = $row['userIngame']; // Replace column_to_display with the column you want the results from
                $output = '<h2 style="color:white;">There are '.$count.' players </h2><br>';
                               } 

        }
}
echo json_encode($s);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html>


<head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("form").submit(function(){
                    var player = <?php echo json_encode($s); ?>;
                    alert("players : " + player);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what do you expect? I suppose your page just reloads and that's why shows results of previous search.

Comment: Try to show your alert on `$(document).ready` not on `form.submit`.

Comment: @u_mulder yes it does. Please  tell me how to fix it

Comment: With ajax request obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what happens when the PHP parts get executed. The first time your page gets displayed, $q is empty. That's why your SQL will return no result. The $output will be set to `'<h2 style="color:white;">No player found!</h2>';` and $s[] will not be set. This is what is written to your page inside the javascript tags...

```
<script> 
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("form").submit(function(){
                    var player = null;
                    alert("players : " + player);
    });
});
</script>
```

That's why, when you sumbit the form, the alert shows null. 
The second time when you display the page, the $q has a value and $s is populated by the SQL call. Now the script will look like this ...

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("form").submit(function(){
                    var player = "Some Playername";
                    alert("players : " + player);
    });
});
</script>
```

The alert function however will only be executed when you submit the form and then it will show the name inside the alert box. But of course, by then, you are expecting the next playername to be shown.

Comment: i understand now. I ll figure it out how to fix it i guess .Thanks for the info

Comment: maybe if i replace submit fuction with on page reload will work?